# How to get the object context in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var viewModel = function (utils) {
        this.x="GNC";
        this.tbl = null; }; viewModel.prototype.saveCords=function(){   alerts(this.x); };

$(function(){

var objViewModel=new viewModel();

$('#btnSaveCords').on('click',objViewModel.saveCords); // this is suppose to alert "GNC", but it doesnt

});
```

So, how do i get the object context in saveCords instead of the button context?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is by default the event handler method will have the context as the dom element targeted by the handler, you need to change that to your custom object.

Use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass a custom execution context to a event handler method.(You can use [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) but there is no support in IE < 9)

```
var viewModel = function (utils) {
    this.x = "GNC";
    this.tbl = null;
};
viewModel.prototype.saveCords = function () {
    alert(this.x);
};

$(function () {

    var objViewModel = new viewModel();

    $('#btnSaveCords').on('click', $.proxy(objViewModel.saveCords, objViewModel)); // this is suppose to alert "GNC", but it doesnt

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/49rTD/)

Answer (score 0):

You should place the parameter

```
var objViewModel=new viewModel(utils_param_here); //here defined in function utils
```

Full code:

```
var viewModel = function (utils) {
        this.x="GNC";
        this.tbl = null; }; viewModel.prototype.saveCords=function(){   alerts(this.x); };

$(function(){

var objViewModel=new viewModel(this);

$('#btnSaveCords').on('click',objViewModel.saveCords); // this is suppose to alert "GNC", but it doesnt

});
```